# Laravel: смена названия broadcast канала и очередь redis

Tags: php, laravel

Тестировал широковещание Ларавел. Просто  по https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting только без приватности и проверки доступа.

Установлено: laravel echo, laravel echo server, socket.io-client, predis

Кейс: меняю название канала в классе события. Т.е:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
        return new Channel('new_channel_name');
}
```

Но название канала не меняется, пока я не перезапущу сервис работы очереди. То что не поменялось смотрю по тому, что отдает laravel-echo-server  в devmode.

Как это работает? Почему я меняю код, но по факту название Канала меняется только при перезапуске обработчика очереди?

Comment: Потому что обработчик очереди запущен как отдельный процесс операционной системы. Он *уже* сидит в памяти, прочитав (загрузив) весь код PHP и выполняя его. И до перезапуска этого процесса у него не возникнет потребности прочитать какой-то код с диска. Это "зацикленный" процесс, он работает в цикле "прочитать состояние очереди - выполнить что появилось - подождать - начать сначала".

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko Спасибо за ответ. Возможно, вы правы. Но тогда выходит, что создание новых Джобов приведет к ошибке, либо их невыполнению, так как их код не сидит в процессе очереди. Надо будет протестировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Laravel каждый Job, включая [описанный в документации обработчик broadcast-событий](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites), оформляется в виде отдельного класса-обработчика. Выполнением этих Job'ов фактически [занимается отдельный процесс операционной системы](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker), запускаемый консольной командой `php artisan queue:work` и являющийся зацикленным процессом с простым алгоритмом:

1. Инициализировать обработчик очереди.
2. Проверить обрабатываемую (ые) очередь (очереди).
3. Если есть Job:

   - прочитать его из очереди;
   - если класс Job'а еще не загружен - загрузить его исходник и исходники всех требуемые ему классов с помощью автозагрузчика;
   - создать экземпляр Job'а;
   - выполнить метод `handle()` в этом экземпляре Job'а;
   - перейти к п.2.
4. Если очередь пуста:

   - подождать некоторое время (задаваемое параметром `--timeout=...`);
   - перейти к п.2

Это, конечно, очень упрощенный алгоритм, но он позволяет понять логику работы. Если у Вас какой-либо Job в этом обработчике уже хотя бы один раз выполнился - то класс этого Job'а, а также все требуемые им классы (в Вашем случае - класс события с названием канала), уже загружены автозагрузчиком в том виде, в котором были на момент первого обращения. Соответственно, внося изменения в исходный код этого Job'а или любого им используемого класса (в Вашем случае - класса события, в котором Вы **меняете** наименование канала), Вы должны перезапустить обработчик. Просто потому, что повторно читать исходный код загруженных классов он не будет - класс **уже** загружен в том виде, в котором он был на момент первого к нему обращения.

Если же Вы создадите новый Job (как пишете в комментарии) и поместите его в очередь выполнения, то, согласно приведенного выше описания алгоритма, обработчик наткнется на неизвестный ему класс и загрузит его с помощью автозагрузчика классов в том виде, в котором он будет на момент первого обращения.

Таким образом, для добавления **новых Job'ов** перезагружать обработчик очереди не нужно. Но вот для того, чтобы заработал **измененный** код, обработчик придется перезапустить. Иначе никак.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! По ссылке на доку написано, что надо перезапускать (пропустил этот момент), либо использовать менее эффективный queue:listen метод. 
Не совсем укладывается в голове, как одновременно job может быть загружен в память, но в то же время отрабатывать по разному с разными параметрами. Но это уже другая история :)

Comment: @Pavel, тут все просто. Представьте себе, что Вы разрабатываете не вэб-приложение, а классическую программу. Вы ее скомпилировали, собрали  и запустили исполняемый файл. Поёрзали немного интерфейс. Потом поняли, что надо что-то изменить. Внесли изменения в исходник, скомпилировали, собрали выполняемую программу - но _не запустили_ ее. И смотрите на работающий экземпляр старой версии, удивляясь, как это может быть - нововведения в ней не видны?.. :)